# affine combination of convex functions.

Tags: convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

In a complete smooth simply connected Riemannian manifold of non-positive curvature, the square of the distance function $d^2(p,x)$ is a smooth strictly convex function of $x$. It follows that this is also true for positive linear combinations. What happens with affine combinations, namely combinations of the form $\sum w_i d^2(p_i,x)$, where $\sum w_i =1$? In euclidean space any affine combination of squared distance functions is strictly convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want *non-positive*, not non-negative curvature. In positively curved spaces $d^2$ is neither smooth nor convex (consider the sphere).

The answer is negative. Consider a geodesic $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$, and on it the affine combination
$$f(t) = 2d^2(\gamma(t),\gamma(0))-d^2(\gamma(t),p) \tag{1}$$
where $p$ is some point in $M$. Since $\gamma$ is a geodesic, (1) simplifies to 
$$f(t) = 2t^2 - d^2(\gamma(t),p) \tag{2}$$
So now you are asking for $d^2(\gamma(t),p)-2t^2$ to be concave, which has the meaning of a *lower* curvature bound. In any sufficiently negatively curved space this property will fail.

Instead of justifying the previous sentence, I'll give a concrete example. Consider the Poincaré disk with the [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric#Metric_and_volume_element_on_the_Poincar.C3.A9_disk) 
$$d(a,b) = \tanh^{-1}\left|\frac{a-b}{1-a\bar b}\right|$$
Consider the geodesic $\gamma(t) = \tanh t$ and the point $p=0.9i$. The function (2) takes the form 
$$2t^2 - \left(\tanh^{-1}\left|\frac{\tanh t-0.9i}{1+0.9 i \tanh t}\right| \right)^{2}$$
which is shown below:

[image: counterexample]